# Get text value of a table specifying a row with jQuery or js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get data of a table row by row to create a string with the data separated by comma. 
The table looks like this:

[image]

I want to have a string with data from table separated by comma (CSV style) as follows:

> myText = Consistently exceeds requirements- Benchmark, 1, Exceeds some requirements, 1, Meets requirements, 2,

The table HTML looks like this:

[image]

I tried the following code but I have not been able to get the value/text of only one row, then ask for next cell in the same row, then jump to next one.

```
console.log($('.sm-data-table-summary').eq(2).text());
```

But it retrieves all table data for second element found in the whole page.

```
csv_string += ($('.sm-data-table-summary > tbody').prop("innerText") + ',');
```

But it gets all data for the table, meaning option text + percentage + numeric value and goes thru all options, not giving me the option to separate with commas

```
$(element).find('.sm-data-table-summary').each(function() {
            console.log($(this).find("tr:nth-child(2)").text());
        });
```

This last one is closest I am to what I want, I got the **2nd** text, percentage and numeric value for each table found in the page. Again all at once not giving me chance to separate by comma.

Do you know a way to get only the option text, then the percentage, then the numeric value of the same row? And then move to next row?

Or maybe is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

```js
var els = $(".sm-data-table-summary").find(".label,.sm-data-total").get();
var myText = els.map(function(e) { return $(e).text(); }).join(",");

// debugging
console.log("texts:", myText);
document.body.innerHTML += myText;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="sm-data-table-summary" border=1>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="label">a-label</div></td>
    <td>a-percent</td>
    <td><div class="sm-data-total">a-1</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="label">b-label</div></td>
    <td>b-percent</td>
    <td><div class="sm-data-total">b-1</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
```

As you can see, this only gets the `label` and `sm-data-total` of each row. If you want the percentage, all you have to do is change the argument to the `.find()`.